# john the ripper, on kali linux it outputs no password hashes loaded

Tags: linux, security, kali-linux

Trying to crack the password using John , I have unshadowed the passwd & shadow file, but it outputs no password hashes loaded, how should unhash

```
john johninput --wordlist=/usr/share/wordlist/rockyou.txt
```

output : no password hashes loaded (see FAQ)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to guess that you're testing this on Kali itself; having ran the following command successfully:

```
sudo unshadow /etc/passwd /etc/shadow > johninput
```

If you view johninput and see **$y$** right after the username, then that indicates the passwords are hashed with **yescrypt**.

```
kali:$y$j9T$B4i9oW2LaERt/J5/X8bbN/$zzGfRqAZim/VofZcas3MhnfSdYddB5.zRulk087PN2A:1000:1000:Kali,,,:/home/kali:/usr/bin/zsh
```

It appears John needs a little help with detecting the hash format, so try changing your command line to the following:

```
john --format=crypt --wordlist=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt johninput
```

Of course the default password for the kali user is solved much faster by simply running:

```
john --format=crypt johninput
```